# blocked activating office 365 cant access internet 0x80004005

Tags: windows-10, office365

So I'm trying to activate my Microsoft office 365 by signing into my account
by I am getting a blocked signed-in error.

[image]

I believe it is the Spybot anti-beacon but when I try to undo it or delete the folder it still does not work Spybot anti-beacon blocking telemetry

[image]

since running an office repair tool I'm now getting Error code: 0x80004005

[image]

Comment: Do you have the latest version of Office installed? sign in problems often occur because you do not have the latest version installed.

Comment: I do have the latest version installed

Comment: You need to verify hosts is restore to the default contents. only contained  Since Office 365 is a subscription, you have to log into your MS account, there isn't another way to activate it (unlike the perpetual license). This question cannot be answered unless your willing to reverse those changes the program made to your hosts file

Answer (score 0):

On this computer, open Regedit to check the following registry key:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\SignIn
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\SignIn

Check if there is an value for "**SignInOptions**". If there is, please **remove** this value **or** **change it to 0**. Then restart Office 2013, check if you can sign in.